# MID-android tablet with no Bluetooth

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

All I ask is for an answer. Can I put a Bluetooth dongle on this tablet and run Bluetooth devices such as a keyboard/cover. It's a MID-android 4.1 with a mini USB port and adapter cable to a full sized USB. Everything else is stock. The kernel is standard 13.something, I think.  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2235485) Bluetooth USB dongle support is native starting from Android 4.2.2. So if you're running 4.0 as the tag suggests, it doesn't work. You'll have to update the tablet.

Also, you'll have to confirm that the USB port supports full host mode with [USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics).